# iOS Firebase Messaging Migration - Updated apps don't receive message, but freshly installed apps do

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've just been trying to migrate my iOS apps over from Google Cloud Messaging to Firebase, and after putting in all the hard work and getting everything working fine for freshly installed apps, I've hit a problem:

> If I install an old version of an app (that used GCM for push notifications), then I update that old version to the new Firebase-based version, I don't receive any messages to the device.

The messages are sent fine from the sender side (I use Postman to test), and they are received fine on the freshly installed apps. I'm making sure that the updated apps are getting the Firebase instance token and sending it to my server database (and log for my manual testing) as always, and since the response for the message send is always successful I'm pretty sure there's no problem with my API Key or push token in general.

Sadly that's about the extent of the information I can provide for my question, feel like I'm banging my head against a wall. It's not good enough to ask my user base to uninstall and reinstall the app from scratch, they'll lose their data! (I already migrated to Firebase for my Android apps, they're working fine.)

Anyone have any experience with this? Meantime I'm going back to GCM, 'twas working just fine...

**EDIT**

As Firebase swizzles methods in the AppDelegate class, it's a lot sparser now, I no longer do anything in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`. (I do have it defined with just an NSLog function call, it gets called, always twice for some reason.)

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` looks a bit like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOption
{
    // Configure Firebase and listen out for token updates
    [FIRApp configure];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onTokenRefresh) name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    //...
}
```

And my `onTokenRefresh:` method is being called fine - I'm getting the new token, I'm able to use it with Postman and server to send out push notifications - I simply don't receive them on the app when it happens to have been updated from a previous incarnation...

```
- (void) onTokenRefresh
{
    NSString *token = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
    NSLog(@"onTokenRefresh called - My Firebase token is: %@", token);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but in the FCM iOS Migration Guide, did you [update the server endpoints](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm#update_server_endpoints)?

Comment: Thanks, but no we didn't - as you see in that same document "Updating these endpoints is not strictly required, as Google will continue to support the existing GCM endpoints." Changing our endpoints would mean older versions of the apps would cease to receive PNs :-( And besides - it works fine for fresh app installs!

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by "then I update that old version to the new Firebase-based version" is this happening through the app store, or are you doing this in your dev environment. If you are calling registerForRemoteNotifications and handling it in your AppDelegate changing from GCM to FCM should not have any effect. Adding relevant parts of your AppDelegate would also be useful.

Comment: " Changing our endpoints would mean older versions of the apps would cease to receive PNs " , so you've actually tested this?

Comment: thanks @noogui - no, and I just realised I was making  a big assumption!.. oops.

Comment: @Mete Aha! Any improvements now?

Comment: @noogui No luck using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send either, sadly... (But thanks for pointing out my negligence! :-) )

Comment: forgive me if I'm missing your point, but I'm still not clear on what you mean by "updated", do you mean you run it with GCM implementation and it works then you update the same app to FCM run it again and it does not work?

Comment: I install app version 1.0, which uses GCM implementation for push notifications. Then in app version 2.0, I've changed the GCM code to use FCM instead. I install this without first deleting version 1.0, and it doesn't work. If I delete version 1.0 and then install 2.0, it does work.

Comment: Hi @Mete did you manage to track down a way to fix this issue? I'm experiencing the same issue.
App in production with GCM, trying to update to FCM. Upgraded apps don't get push messages. New installs of the app with FCM work fine.
So can't really move to FCM as that would mean our existing users won't get push messages and might not ever open our app again. (We use push notifications to inform them of new content)

Comment: @beanmonger sorry no luck yet - I've still got our iOS codebase using the old GCM setup.

Comment: I'm having this problem too, but the old version of the app was installed along with Parse, in the new version we have removed Parse and used FCM, the notifications are delivered only on new installs but not on app updates, we tried to send notifications from firebase console it says it's been sent but not delivered (on app updates). do anybody have a solution to this weird problem ?